# Java resource not found in Jar, in web app in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, resources, classloader

I have a web app running in Tomcat 8 and this web app war files includes several jars (through Spring framework). One of them is a jar called connector.jar. This connector.jar contains a method that receives a package name, and the method checks if a certain file is present. I am sure the file is present (triple checked it, also in the jar file), so in development, when running as exploded jar, it returns true, but when it's packaged in a jar and deployed as a war in Tomcat, it returns false.

Please help me understand what the problem can be, and how to solve this or debug it?

The method:

```
public boolean isPresent(String packageName) {
 return getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(packageName + "index.json") != null;
}
```

Notes:

- Example of the package name: "com/bla/connector/" (the package name
  doesn't contain a leading "/").
- I also used class.getResource(), but same result. In SO the advised
  not to use this when finding a resource in a jar, as you might use
  the wrong class loader. I am using ActiveMQ embedded in the same war.
- The code can be called by a Queue Consumer. But I don't think that is
  a problem the way I am using the ClassLoader.

UPDATE, some more details as requested:

- I use maven as build tool (latest version), and maven builds the war. I use the default maven war layout. WEB-INF/classes, WEB-INF/lib. The lib folder contains all the jar, and the connector.jar.
- The method isPresent is located in the connector.jar in the class com.company.HtmlWorker.
- The files index.json is located in the package: com.company.json.account.
- Output of the isPresent method when logging the created index.json name: "com/company/json/account/index.json"

Comment: Can you break down what the war looks like internally? Where are the jar files? Where is the index.json file inside the jar inside the war? Where is the class that has the isPresent() method? Also, please add logging to that "isPresent()" method to log out the exact package name it is receiving; collect hard proof that when deployed as a war the package name being put there is indeed as you expect it to be.

Comment: @Gimby: I broke it down. So what do you think?

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. I don't see a single thing wrong here. Try a wild experimentation: put a random file like a text file in the root of the jar, and try to load that using getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bla.txt"); Does that also not work? Also try to deploy on a secondary completely fresh installation of Tomcat, just to be sure.

Comment: Lots of time as passed, did you figure out what was wrong?